# MacOS - Unable to transfer files with Android File Transfer as 2 popups conflicts with each other

Tags: file-transfer, macos, samsung-galaxy-s-10, usb-c

When I connect my phone to my Macbook, I see a popup saying I need to allow permissions on my phone (see screenshot).

[image]

So I click 'Allow' on my phone. Now the error popup still stays while the main window shows the content of my phone. But I am unable to click on the main window because the error popup is still open.

When I click OK on the error popup, both the error popup and the main window closes together and the error popup opens again with the 'Allow' confirmation on my phone. If I click 'Allow', it all repeats over.

[image]

See the GIF for what I'm talking about.

```
Model - Samsung Galaxy S10 Plus
Android version - 12
One UI version - 4.1
Mac OS version - 12.6
Android File Transfer - I think it's latest but can't find the version as the popup blocks me from checking the About menu.
```

Is this a bug with the Android File Transfer? Is there an another free app that I can use to transfer files?

Comment: In my opinion this is more a MacOS question than an Android question.